# Getting a list of client MAC addresses on a home router

Tags: python, linux, macos, networking, network-programming

I am building a small project for my self and came across a small issue.

I have a wifi router, to which I can connect by typing 192.168.0.1 and then entering my browser. It opens a standard D-Link website. There I can see a list of clients currently connected to the router.

I need to get the same information programmatically. Preferably using python, but I can also live with a Linux solution.

Is there a way to do this? I googled around but nothing I found worked for me.

Comment: This can be done by scraping the loaded webpage, collect the connected mac address etc.  Alternatively, if you are on linux box, it is even easy, as I can write a code to return connected MAC address

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But I'm not willing to write it for you :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a free-coding request.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of just scraping it but it seems such a dirty solution. Was wondering if there is a cleaner way! @LasVegasCoder

Comment: @TruniTr see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

#### Get List of Connected Device's IP and MAC Address from your router.

On *nix | Linux use:

```
netdiscover -i eth0
```

On Windows use:

```
arp -a
```